# How to validate has_one relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these two models

User.rb

`has_one :bike`

Bike.rb

`belongs_to :user`

If a `user` tries to create multiple `bikes`, then the has_one relation doesn't make sense.

How can I add validation for this condition in the model level?

How can I make sure that the `user` will be always having one bike?

Comment: Create a `before_create` callback in `bike.rb` file. Check if the `current_user.bike` has any record or not. If record exists then add an error and return

Comment: On StackOverflow, it is best practice to accept the answer that best solves your issue, to help the community and future googlers navigate through relevant questions / answers. It also closes the question :) Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Create a `before_create` callback in **bike.rb** file. Check if the `current_user.bike` has any record or not. If record exists then add an error and return.

```
class Bike < ApplicationRecord

  # Associations
  has_one :user

  before_create :user_exists

  private
  def user_exists
    if self.user.bike.present?
      errors[:base] << "Add your validation message here"
      return false
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a `validates_uniqueness_of` call on your `Bike` model.

```rb
class Bike < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id
end
```